# When saying "was not a child" should I say 子供じゃなかった or 子じゃなかった?

Tags: word-choice

If the kanji for child is 子 why is 子供 also child? In which cases would I say one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

子供 means kids or children in general.

子, apart from kid or child, can also mean "son" or "daughter". So if you say「子じゃなかった」sometimes it means he/she isn't my/your... son/daugther.

In the case of your question, you should say 「子供じゃなかった」. That means "he/she was not a child".

Comment: When you say 子供 means kids or children in general, does that mean it is plural?

Comment: It can be singular or plural, just like pretty much everything else.